# How to solve $\frac{8x+3}5-\frac{11x-9}6+\frac{4x+3}{15}=\frac{11x+15}{10}$

Tags: fractions

Here's an equation:
$$\frac{8x+3}5-\frac{11x-9}6+\frac{4x+3}{15}=\frac{11x+15}{10}$$

It looks simple, and I know the answer $- 3/4$, but can't arrive at it. Instead, I arrive at $1.75$ by reducing all the fractions to a common denominator $- 30$. Could anyone show the correct solution method?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $30$ and solve the corresponding equation.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{8x+3}{5} - \frac{11x-9}{6} + \frac{4x+3}{15} = \frac{11x+15}{10}$

$6(8x+3) - 5(11x-9) + 2(4x+3) = 3(11x+15)$

$x + 69 = 33x + 45$

$32x = 24$

$x = \frac{24}{32} = \frac{3}{4}$